# Where is the state saved for arbitrary state processing using mapGroupsWithState?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am using `mapGroupsWithState` on a streaming dataset to maintain state across batches. Where is this data/state stored? Executors, the driver or somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but I am not sure where this data/state is stored? (Executor or driver)

State is persisted to `[checkpointLocation]/state` that should be on a reliable HDFS-compliant distributed file system so executors (and tasks) can access it when required.

That gives `[checkpointLocation]/state`.

There could be many stateful operators, each with its own `operatorId` that is used to store operator-specific state. That's why you may have zero, one or more state subdirectories for every stateful operator.

That gives `[checkpointLocation]/state/[operatorId]`.

There are even more subdirectories in stateful operator-specific state directory for partitions.

That gives the following state-specific directory layout:

```
[checkpointLocation]/state/[operatorId]/[partitionId]
```

Use web UI to find out the `checkpointLocation`, `operatorId` and the number of partitions.

The state of a stateful operator is recreated from `[checkpointLocation]/state` using `StateStoreRestoreExec` unary physical operator (use `explain` to find it). `StateStoreRestoreExec` restores (reads) a streaming state from a state store for the keys that are given by the child physical operator. My understanding is that the state is recreated every micro-batch.

Comment: Thanks @JacekLaskowski for detailed answer. Using the pointers you gave, I will try to find out if state is created from checkpoint location files or from in memory data structures. As creating state  from hdfs/s3 in each microbatch is not ideal and will increase the batch processing time

Comment: Hi @Jacek does this mean the state is not saved in memory at all? it's saved directly to the checkpoint location!

Comment: It's in the checkpoint location after it's been used and computed (hence in memory).

Comment: created the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66369089/2201566 I think it's somehow related. but by question is about where it's stored in memory